# Wie sagt man »space for milk« auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

If I order a coffee, say an Americano, and I would like extra room in the cup for milk that I’m going to add myself, how would I ask for that extra space in the cup?

- > Platz für Milch
- > Raum für Milch
- etwas anderes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Bitte machen sie die Tasse nicht ganz voll, [denn] ich möchte noch Milch dazu geben.

In an informal context you could say:

> Bitte nicht ganz voll machen, [denn] ich nehme noch Milch.

Comment: For me as german native this Sounds more natural than the direkt translation of martin peters

Comment: Dankeschön. Sehr hilfreich.

Answer (score 9):

Z. B. : *Lassen Sie etwas Platz für die Milch.*

oder

*Machen Sie das Glas nicht ganz voll; ich gebe noch Milch dazu.*

Comment: Habe im Café gejobt und trinke in der Pause täglich Kaffee mit Kollegen. "Einen kleinen Kaffee mit Platz für Milch, bitte." ist die gängigste Bestellung, die ich kenne.